# why my file_put_contents call create a zero byte image?

Tags: php, curl

I am trying to create a site that use amazon api to display book information. However, some images I downloaded is showing 0 byte. The code is running on a virtual serever, so curl is enabled.

For example, this image: [http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51d1Zp4f80L.*SL75*.jpg](http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/51d1Zp4f80L._SL75_.jpg)

My code is this:

```
try
{
    $ch = curl_init($coverImageUrl);
    $imgName = "images/".$isbn.".png"; //assume png
    $imgFullPath = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/".$imgName;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $fb = curl_exec($ch);
    if($fb === false) {
        echo 'something wrong';
        }

    curl_close($ch);
    file_put_contents( $imgFullPath, $fb );
    }
    catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
    die("problem with image");
}
```

Comment: use the API, or things like this will happen

Comment: what api? I am using amazon api. Don't know what you mean

Comment: If I use $img = file_get_contents($coverImageUrl), it actually works. So what is wrong with my curl function?

Comment: When the error happens, print out the result of `curl_info($ch)` to see what headers and other data you've received. It may help you diagnose connection or other problems.

Comment: strange, I reverted the file_get_contents and put my curl function back, now, curl function also works!!??????